# Implementing a BMI Calculator in C

Tags: c, calculator

I am having trouble making the BMI calculator program and I am wondering what I haven't done correctly. I am a beginner so go easy on me, thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    // Variables for height, weight, and bmi
    float height;
    float weight;
    float bmi;

    printf("\aEnter your height: ");
    scanf(" %f", height);

    printf("\a\nEnter your weight: ");
    scanf(" %f", weight);

    bmi = (height * 4.88) / (weight * weight);

    printf("\a\nYour BMI is: %f", bmi);
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, what are the symptoms?  Have you attempted to debug it at all yet?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Please remember that in order to help answer your question, we need to know exactly what's going wrong with it, and what you have tried.  Thanks for asking!

Comment: Yes, I have tried multiple things and when I try to run it in code blocks, after i enter the height, it says bmiCalc.exe has stopped working.

Comment: Mind if I ask why every printf call has a bell character?

Comment: I just want it to. Its not required

Answer (score 4):

scanf requires a pointer to parameters following the format string.
Use the & operator thus:

```
printf("\aEnter your height: ");
scanf(" %f", &height);

printf("\a\nEnter your weight: ");
scanf(" %f", &weight);
```

Comment: okay, my program is working now, but it isnt calculating the BMI correctly. this is the output:

Comment: @HayesDerbyshire There is no output?

Comment: check the BMI formula - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_mass_index suggests it is w / h * h

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass the address of your variables to [scanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), so that it can modify the values at that address:

```
scanf(" %f", &height);
             ^
             \ Address-of operator (Returns the memory address of the float)
```

And:

```
scanf(" %f", &weight);
```